# All common columns from 2 datasets not getting returned on inner join in R

Tags: r, merge, inner-join

I am inner joining 2 datasets on 2 sets of columns

```
wonoppsp1_rr <- merge(x = wonoppsp1_dodge,
y = rentalresults,
by.x = c("Result.ID","Result.Rental.Sale.Doc.."), 
by.y = c("Display_Account","Order_Number"))

Dataset 1 - wonoppsp1_dodge
Dataset 2 - rentalresults
```

The resulting dataset does not return the `"Display_Account"` and `"Order_Number"` columns from the `rentalresults dataset`.

How can I get these included in the dataset as well?

Comment: please share a reproducable example

Comment: I suppose the columns are in the result but with the names given by `by.x=`.

Comment: So, the join is happening fine, but I wanted to know if we can get all common columns from both datasets in the final table.

Comment: @jogo Yes, only the by.x columns are showing up. How can I get by,y columns in as well?

Comment: @ThomasVarghese Why should the matched values be twice in the result (the same values with column name from the first dataframe and with column name from the second dataframe)?

Comment: @jogo Yes, you are right on that. That makes sense. Sorry - was a foolish question